# My object isn't updating by reference, what's wrong with the logic?

Tags: javascript

I've been working with this bug for a few days now, and I think I've pinpointed the problem area, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I think it may have to do with [a problem with passing an object by reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass), but if that's the case I'm not sure how to apply that solution to my situation.

Basically, I'm working on (as a learning experience) my own implementation of dependency injection (although I've been told my structure is actually called [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), I'll keep using "DI" until I understand more about the difference). So I'll briefly explain my code, then highlight the problematic part.

---

### The syntax:

This is what my code should do, it's just very very simple DI.

I created scope with a string path, using `"/scopeName/subScopeName:componentName"` to select a scope, so that code users can select the scope while defining the component in a simple way, using a `":"` to select a component from the scope.

There are no interfaces since it's so simple to type check in JS. There are no special component types such as factories, values, etc, every component is treated equally.

```
var JHTML = new Viziion('JHTML');
JHTML.addScope('/generate');

/* ... snip ... */

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:process', function(nodes) {
  /* ... snip - the code inside isn't important here - snip ..*/
}).inject(['/generate:jsonInput']);
```

The `inject` function just takes an array of component paths in the order the component's arguments are expected.

Hooks are components stored in the `hooks` property, and then there's a function `returnUserHandle` which will return an object consisting of just the hooks, so all of the functions are hidden in closures, and you can feed the code user just the usable methods.

```
JHTML.addHook('generate', function(jsonInput, process) {
   var html = process(jsonInput);
   return html;
}).inject(['/generate:jsonInput', '/generate:process']);

var handle = JHTML.returnUserHandle();

/* HTML Generator Syntax - Client */

console.log(handle.generate());
```

---

### The problem:

To point `inject` to the correct object intuitively, there's a `focus` property on the main object, and I thought I could use `that.focus` ( which is a reference to `this.focus`) within my different methods such as `addComponent` and `inject` to link new functions to the correct location in my scope model and have them still referenced in `focus` after being created with `addComponent` or after being called by the `focusComponent` method, and then `inject` could find the dependencies, and "wire" them by doing this:

```
that.focus = function() {
   that.focus.apply(null, dependencies);
};
```

And I thought that would package the dependencies (an array) as a closure and when the code user calls the function, the correct dependencies get applied and that's the ball game. But nope. The functions dont seem to be passing by reference from `that.focus` into the scope model. `that.focus` updates, but the scope model does not.

**What's wrong with my reference logic?**

---

### The code:

Here's a simplified version of the code. I think I've done my best to explain how it works and where exactly the reference problem I'm trying to solve is located.

```js
    /* Dependency Injection Framework - viziion.js */

    function Viziion() {
      var that = this;

      //here's the focus property I mentioned
      this.focus = null;

      this.scope = {
        '/': {
          'subScopes': {},
          'components': {}
        }
      };
      this.hooks = {};

      this.addScope = function(scopeName) {
        /* the way this works inst relevant to the problem */
      };

      this.addComponent = function(componentName, func) {

        var scopeArray = // snip 
          // snip - just code to read the component path

          for (var i = 0; i <= scopeArray.length; i++) {
            if (scopeArray[i] !== "") {
              if (scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]]) {
                scope = scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]];
              } else if (i == scopeArray.length) {

                // And here's where I add the component to the scope model
                // and reference that component in the focus property
                scope.components[scopeName] = func;
                that.focus = scope.components[scopeName];

              } else {
                throw 'Scope path is invalid.';
              }
            }
          }
      } else {
        throw 'Path does not include a component.';
      }
      return that;
    };

    this.returnComponent = function(componentName, callback) {
      /* ... snip ... */
    };

    this.addHook = function(hookName, func) {
      /* ... snip ... */
    };

    this.inject = function(dependencyArray) {
      if (dependencyArray) {
        var dependencies = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < dependencyArray.length; i++) {
          that.returnComponent(dependencyArray[i], function(dependency) {
            dependencies.push(dependency);
          });
        }
        that.focus = function() {
          that.focus.apply(null, dependencies);
        };
        return that;
      }
    };

    /* ... snip - focusComponent - snip ... */

    /* ... snip - returnUserHandle - snip ... */
```

This should, when applied as shown up above under the "Syntax" header, produce a console log with a string of HTML.

Instead, I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, corresponding to the line `var html = process(jsonInput);`.

---

If you want to test the full code, all together, here it is:

```js
/* Dependency Injection Framework - viziion.js */

function Viziion(appName) {
  if (typeof appName == 'string') {
    var that = this;
    this.name = appName;
    this.focus = null;
    this.scope = {
      '/': {
        'subScopes': {},
        'components': {}
      }
    };
    this.hooks = {};

    this.addScope = function(scopeName) {
      if (typeof scopeName == 'string') {
        var scopeArray = scopeName.split('/');
        var scope = that.scope['/'];
        for (var i = 0; i < scopeArray.length; i++) {
          if (scopeArray[i] !== "") {
            if (scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]]) {
              scope = scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]];
            } else {
              scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]] = {
                'subScopes': {},
                'components': {}
              };
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        throw 'Scope path must be a string.';
      }
      return that;
    };

    this.addComponent = function(componentName, func) {
      if (typeof componentName == 'string') {
        var scopeArray = componentName.split(':');
        if (scopeArray.length == 2) {
          var scope = that.scope['/'];
          var scopeName = scopeArray[1];
          scopeArray = scopeArray[0].split('/');
          for (var i = 0; i <= scopeArray.length; i++) {
            if (scopeArray[i] !== "") {
              if (scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]]) {
                scope = scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]];
              } else if (i == scopeArray.length) {
                scope.components[scopeName] = func;
                that.focus = scope.components[scopeName];
              } else {
                throw 'Scope path is invalid.';
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          throw 'Path does not include a component.';
        }
      } else {
        throw 'Component path must be a string.';
      }
      return that;
    };

    this.returnComponent = function(componentName, callback) {
      if (typeof componentName == 'string') {
        var scopeArray = componentName.split(':');
        if (scopeArray.length == 2) {
          var scope = that.scope['/'];
          var scopeName = scopeArray[1];
          scopeArray = scopeArray[0].split('/');
          for (var i = 0; i <= scopeArray.length; i++) {
            if (scopeArray[i] !== "") {
              if (i == scopeArray.length) {
                callback(scope.components[scopeName]);
              } else if (scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]]) {
                scope = scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]];
              } else {
                throw 'Scope path is invalid.';
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          throw 'Path does not include a component.';
        }
      } else {
        throw 'Component path must be a string.';
      }
    };

    this.addHook = function(hookName, func) {
      if (typeof hookName == 'string') {
        that.hooks[hookName] = func;
        that.focus = that.hooks[hookName];
      } else {
        throw 'Hook name must be a string.';
      }
      return that;
    };

    this.inject = function(dependencyArray) {
      if (dependencyArray) {
        var dependencies = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < dependencyArray.length; i++) {
          that.returnComponent(dependencyArray[i], function(dependency) {
            dependencies.push(dependency);
          });
        }
        console.log(that.focus);
        that.focus = function() {
          that.focus.apply(null, dependencies);
        };
        console.log(that.focus);
        console.log(that.scope);
        return that;
      }
    };

    this.focusComponent = function(componentPath) {
      that.focus = that.returnUserHandle(componentPath);
    };

    this.returnUserHandle = function() {
      return that.hooks;
    };

  } else {
    throw 'Viziion name must be a string.';
  }
}

/* JSON HTML Generator - A Simple Library Using Viziion */

var JHTML = new Viziion('JHTML');

JHTML.addScope('/generate');

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:jsonInput', [{
  tag: '!DOCTYPEHTML'
}, {
  tag: 'html',
  children: [{
    tag: 'head',
    children: []
  }, {
    tag: 'body',
    children: []
  }]
}]);

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:process', function(nodes) {
  var html = [];
  var loop = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      if (nodes[i].tag) {
        html.push('<' + tag + '>');
        if (nodes[i].children) {
          loop();
        }
        html.push('</' + tag + '>');
        return html;
      } else {
        throw '[JHTML] Bad syntax: Tag type is not defined on node.';
      }
    }
  };
}).inject(['/generate:jsonInput']);



JHTML.addHook('generate', function(jsonInput, process) {
  console.log('Process func arg:');
  console.log(process);
  var html = process(jsonInput);
  return html;
}).inject(['/generate:jsonInput', '/generate:process']);

var handle = JHTML.returnUserHandle();

/* HTML Generator Syntax - Client */

console.log(handle.generate());
```

Comment: You mean in the `.inject()`? You're passing an Array, but then copying its values into a new Array. I don't know if that's what you're referring to. You would do well to make a reduced example of the code rather than trying to describe what it does.

Comment: Please distil your question.

Comment: The issue is, all four of those slightly big functions are used together, at once. So I dont know any way of separating the logic without eliminating the problem from my example code.

Comment: He's saying what I said. Get rid of the needless verbosity in your question and code and you'll get more people willing to analyze it. That doesn't mean reduce its complexity. It just means get rid of the cruft. To be an appropriate question for SO, the code should be reduced to a *minimal* example and included directly here in the question instead of on some other site.

Comment: @squint the code is included here in the question. Click on "Show Code Snippet"

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that below the link. Still, I've had many extremely complex problems where an entire application gets reduced down to a handful of lines because I cut the fat. Then it becomes simple to focus on the immediate issue and to give a terse, step by step instruction to demonstrate the problem, describe the desired output and describe what's happening instead.

Comment: One thing jumps out at me. In your code, `that` is not a function (assuming you're calling `new Viziion(...)`). So `that.apply(null, dependencies);` doesn't make much sense to me, unless you've given your object an `.apply()` method somewhere else.

Comment: @squint Sorry that was a bug it was supposed to be `that.focus.apply()`, but when fixed, that doesn't change the issue I think, I just tested it and fixed it in the question. And yeah I would like to cut the question size down, I made an edit which shrunk it a little but... I still dont know what I can delete without reducing the clarity of the problem. It seems like the code is all so relevant to the problem... Perhaps you could suggest which parts I should eliminate from the question?

Comment: At the bottom of your code example, please put just a couple lines that show how `Viziion` should be called to reproduce the issue. Describe exactly what you expect and exactly what happens instead. That will help to show what can be reduced. I see lots of string manipulation and error throwing that should have nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @squint ok, questions: 1) I made an abridged version of the code, is it simplified enough? 2) What parts should I now remove from the explanatory areas of my question?

Comment: Well, far as I can see, your `.addHook()` assigns the callback function to `that.hooks.generate`, then `returnUserHandle();` returns `that.hooks` and `handle.generate()` calls the callback you added in `.addHook()`. You're not passing `.generate()` any arguments, so obviously the `process` parameter will be `undefined`. This can be replicated even with eliminating the vast majority of your code.

Comment: @squint when injected, `generate` is supposed to be converted to a function: `function () {  that.focus.apply(null, dependencies); }` I expected the dependencies to be stored in a closure, and for generate to output the result without taking any arguments, because it actually should not be a function without any args. That may sound confusing but it makes more sense in context of the actual code.

Comment: I don't see anything there that would have any impact on the functions held by `that.hooks`. Your `that.focus()` seems to be making a recursive call to itself without an escape, so if that ever does get called, your program will freeze. It does indeed close over the `dependencies` variable, but again, there's nothing there that would impact `that.hooks.generate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big question, bigger answer. Let's get started.

## Heavy OOP, Proper Scope

First and foremost, from your code, it looks like you maybe don't fully grasp the concept of `this`.

Unless you change the execution context of an object's methods beforehand, said object's methods always have their contextual `this` bound to the object instance.

That is:

```
function A () {
  var that = this;
  this.prop = 1;
  this.method = function () {
    console.log(that.prop);
  };
}

new A().method();
```

is generally equivalent to:

```
function A () {
  this.prop = 1;

  this.method = function () {
    console.log(this.prop);
  };
}

new A().method();
```

unless `method` is adjusted before execution with `.bind`, `.call`, or `.apply`.

Why does this matter? Well, if we use our `this` context properly we can utilize object prototypes. Prototypes serve as a far more elegant solution to defining every method of an object on a per-instance basis.

Here we create two instances, but only ever one `method`.

```
function A () {
  this.prop = 1;
}

A.prototype.method = function () {
  console.log(this.prop);
};

new A().method();
new A().method();
```

This is important for clarity, and later on is important when you are binding contexts and arguments to functions **(!)**.

## Code Hygiene

You can skip this topic if you like (head down to The Problems(s)), since it might be considered out of place, but keep in mind it does relate to part of the problem with the code.

Your code is hard to read.

Here are some thoughts on that.

### Prototypes

Use them. You shouldn't need to worry about users changing execution contexts on you, as that's probably a misuse of your program. Security shouldn't be a concern considering they have the source code.

Not much else to say here.

### Exit early

If you're doing sanity checks, try to opt out as early in your code as you can. If you need to `throw` because of a type mismatch, `throw` right then and there - not 27 lines later.

```
// Not great
if (typeof input === 'string') {
  ...
} else throw 'it away';


// Better
if (typeof input !== 'string') throw 'it away';
...
```

This goes for loops as well - making appropriate use of the `continue` keyword. Both of these things improve code clarity, and reduce nesting and code bloat.

### Loop caching

When you're looping over a data structure, and you plan to use the current element several times within the block, you should save that element in a variable. Accessing elements and properties isn't necessarily a free-OP.

```
// Not great
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] > 5) callback(myArray[i]);

  internalArray.push(myArray[i]);
}

// Better
var len = myArray.length, element;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  element = myArray[i];

  if (element > 5) callback(element);

  internalArray.push(element);
}
```

When used correctly this improves both clarity and performance.

## The Problem(s)

First off, what are we *really* doing here? The whole problem boils down to an overly complicated application of function binds. That is, simply changing the execution contexts of functions.

I'll also state outright that this program has no *bug* - it's just flawed.

The major crux of the problem would be these three lines

```
that.focus = function() {
  that.focus.apply(null, dependencies);
};
```

found in the `inject` method. They don't make any sense. This would cause an infinite recursion, plain and simple. When you define that function, it doesn't care at all what the `focus` property of `that` *is* right then and there. That matters solely at *execution* time.

Lucky for us, we never actually get that far, since the `process` component doesn't get bound correctly.

A huge part of the problem is the `focus` property. In your program, you're using this as a sort of most recent action. A singular history as to what has just occurred. The problem is, you've tried to hot-swap this value in strange ways.

The `focus` property (and as you'll see later, other properties) *is* needed however, because of the reverse application of `inject`. The way you've structured your component/hook registers into `inject` model requires state to be held between method invocations.

As an end note for this section, the `process` component function definition would never have returned anything. Even if your model was correct, your input was flawed. `handle.generate()` would have returned `undefined` *always*.

## The Answer(s)

So how can we fix this? Well, the first idea would be to scrap it, honestly. The reverse injection model is ugly, in my opinion. The level of indirection involved with the `inject` method is very confusing from the surface.

But then we wouldn't learn anything, would we?

So really, how do we fix this? Well, much to the dismay of the functional programmers reading, we need to hold *more state*.

On its own, our `focus` property can't provide enough information to properly change the execution contexts of our functions.

On top of our `focus`, which will simply hold a reference to our most recent component value, we need the `field` (component/hook name), and the `fragment` (component object, nothing if hook).

Using these two or three values inside `inject`, we can take our `depedancies` array, `bind` it to our `focus`, and set the resulting function back into our `field`.

The great thing about the next part is we can actually drop our closure by making the contextual `this` of our component/hook the unbound function.

The whole operation looks like this:

```
var focus = this.focus,
    fragment = this.fragment,
    field = this.field,
    hook = function hook () {
      return this.apply(null, arguments);
    }, func;

dependencies.unshift(focus);
func = Function.prototype.bind.apply(hook, dependencies);

if (fragment) fragment[field] = func;
else this.hooks[field] = func;
```

Most of this should be pretty straight forward, but there is one piece that may give people some issues. The important thing to remember is we are essentially creating *two* functions in sequence here, 'discarding' the first in a sense. (It should be noted that this can be done another way with `hook.bind.apply`, but it creates even more confusing code. This is about as elegant as you can get.)

```
dependencies.unshift(focus);
func = Function.prototype.bind.apply(hook, dependencies);
```

First, we add our `focus` (our original function) to the front of our list of dependencies. This is important in a moment.

Then we invoke `Function.prototype.bind` *using* `Function.prototype.apply` (remembering that function prototype methods also share the function prototype methods. Pretty much turtles all the way down).

Now we pass our bind context, `hook`, and our prefixed dependencies to `apply`.

`hook` is used as the *host* for bind, whose contextual `this` is altered by the first element of the array of arguments passed to `apply`. The remaining elements are unrolled to shape the subsequent arguments of `bind`, thus creating the bound arguments of the resulting function.

This isn't a very simple concept, so take your time.

The other thing to note is I've dropped `focusComponent` completely. Its implementation didn't make sense in context. Your model relies on a last input injection, so you'll need to re-implement `focusComponent` as a method that simply adjusts the `focus`, `field`, and `fragment` states.

A small sub-fix is the `process` component function. Not going to go into detail here. You can compare and contrast with your original code, the differences are pretty obvious.

```js
JHTML.addComponent('/generate:process', function (nodes) {
  return (function build (struct, nodes) {
    var length = nodes.length, node, tag;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      tag = node.tag;

      if (!tag) throw '[JHTML] Bad syntax: Tag type is not defined on node.';

      struct.push('<' + tag + '>');

      if (node.children) {
        build(struct, node.children)
        struct.push('</' + tag + '>');
      }
    }

    return struct;
  }([], nodes));
}).inject(['/generate:jsonInput']);
```

## The Code

Below is what I would consider a fixed version of your code. It's written in a style that I find useful for both clarity and performance.

```js
/* Dependency Injection Framework - viziion.js */

function Scope () {
  this.subScopes = {};
  this.components = {};
}

function Viziion (appName) {
  if (typeof appName !== 'string') throw 'Viziion name must be a string.';

  this.name = appName;
  this.working = this.field = this.focus = null
  this.scope = { '/': new Scope() };
  this.hooks = {};
}

Viziion.prototype.addScope = function (scopeName) {
  if (typeof scopeName !== 'string') throw 'Scope path must be a string.';

  var scopeArray = scopeName.split('/'),
      scope = this.scope['/'],
      len = scopeArray.length,
      element, sub;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    element = scopeArray[i];
    if (element === '') continue;

    sub = scope.subScopes[element]

    if (sub) scope = sub;
    else scope.subScopes[element] = new Scope();
  }

  return this;
};

Viziion.prototype.addComponent = function (componentName, func) {
  if (typeof componentName !== 'string') throw 'Component path must be a string.';

  var scopeArray = componentName.split(':'),
      len, element, sub;
  if (scopeArray.length != 2) throw 'Path does not include a component.';

  var scope = this.scope['/'],
      scopeName = scopeArray[1];

  scopeArray = scopeArray[0].split('/');
  len = scopeArray.length;

  for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    element = scopeArray[i];
    if (element === '') continue;

    sub = scope.subScopes[element];

    if (sub) scope = sub;
    else if (i === len) {
      this.fragment = scope.components;
      this.field = scopeName;
      this.focus = scope.components[scopeName] = func;
    }
    else throw 'Scope path is invalid';
  };

  return this;
};

Viziion.prototype.returnComponent = function (componentName, callback) {
  if (typeof componentName !== 'string') throw 'Component path must be a string.';

  var scopeArray = componentName.split(':'),
      len, element, sub;
  if (scopeArray.length != 2) throw 'Path does not include a component.';

  var scope = this.scope['/'],
      scopeName = scopeArray[1];

  scopeArray = scopeArray[0].split('/');
  len = scopeArray.length;

  for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    element = scopeArray[i];
    if (element === '') continue;
    sub = scope.subScopes[element]

    if (i === len) callback(scope.components[scopeName]);
    else if (sub) scope = sub;
    else throw 'Scope path is invalid';
  }
};

Viziion.prototype.addHook = function (hook, func) {
  if (typeof hook !== 'string') throw 'Hook name must be a string.';
  this.fragment = null;
  this.field = hook;
  this.focus = this.hooks[hook] = func;
  return this;
};

Viziion.prototype.inject = function (dependancyArray) {
  if (!dependancyArray) return;

  var dependencies = [],
      len = dependancyArray.length,
      element;

  function push (dep) { dependencies.push(dep); }

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    element = dependancyArray[i];
    this.returnComponent(element, push);
  }

  var focus = this.focus,
      fragment = this.fragment,
      field = this.field,
      hook = function hook () {
        return this.apply(null, arguments);
      }, func;

  dependencies.unshift(focus);
  func = Function.prototype.bind.apply(hook, dependencies);

  if (fragment) fragment[field] = func;
  else this.hooks[field] = func;

  return this;
};

Viziion.prototype.returnUserHandle = function () { return this.hooks; };

/* JSON HTML Generator - A Simple Library Using Viziion */

var JHTML = new Viziion('JHTML');

JHTML.addScope('/generate');

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:jsonInput', [{
  tag: '!DOCTYPE html'
}, {
  tag: 'html',
  children: [{
    tag: 'head',
    children: []
  }, {
    tag: 'body',
    children: []
  }]
}]);

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:process', function (nodes) {
  return (function build (struct, nodes) {
    var length = nodes.length, node, tag;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      tag = node.tag;

      if (!tag) throw '[JHTML] Bad syntax: Tag type is not defined on node.';

      struct.push('<' + tag + '>');

      if (node.children) {
        build(struct, node.children)
        struct.push('</' + tag + '>');
      }
    }

    return struct;
  }([], nodes));
}).inject(['/generate:jsonInput']);

JHTML.addHook('generate', function (jsonInput, process) {
  return process(jsonInput);
}).inject(['/generate:jsonInput', '/generate:process']);


var handle = JHTML.returnUserHandle();

console.log(JHTML);

/* HTML Generator Syntax - Client */

console.log(handle.generate());
```

Comment: Thank you for you time, I'll +100 this in two days when eligible for bounty ^_^

Comment: This really has clarified my understanding of JS. After reading JavaScript the Good Parts by Douglas Crockford, this answer clarified concepts  I read about but didnt really quite understand the first time around. Thanks for the thorough lesson. I'm still reading through it, but so far it all makes sense

Comment: Cheers. If you like books, I'd seriously advise taking a look at [Eloquent](http://eloquentjavascript.net/). I think it does a far better job of introducing the language and its core concepts than _The Good Parts_ (which by all rights is a very dated book these days).

Comment: Ok, I will read it! Again, I cant express how much I appreciate such a detailed, patient, and thorough answer. You seem to have the expressiveness and patience of a teacher, you wouldn't happen to be a CS professor would you?